# Create a scale made up of multiple domains

Tags: d3.js

How can I define a D3 scale with multiple domains making up one range?

**Example**

In this example, I have 3 domains of different sizes, and I want them to translate to equal thirds of the range.

**What I want to do:**

```
const yScale = linearScale()
  .domain([ [0, 10], [11, 50], [51, 500] ])
  .range([0, 100])
```

**What I'm currently doing:**

```
const yScale1 = linearScale().domain([0, 10]).range([0, 33]);
const yScale2 = linearScale().domain([11, 50]).range([34, 66]);
const yScale3 = linearScale().domain([51, 500]).range([67, 100]);

if (val > 51) { 
  return yScale3(val);
} else if (val > 11) { 
  return yScale2(val);
} else {
  return yScale1(val);
}
```

Answer (score 2):

D3 linear scales allow you to pass several values for both domain and range. As explained in the [API](https://github.com/d3/d3-scale#continuous_domain):

> Although continuous scales typically have two values each in their domain and range, specifying more than two values produces a piecewise scale.

In your case, those would be:

```
const scale = d3.scaleLinear()
    .domain([0,10,50,500])
    .range([0, 33.3, 66.6, 100]);
```

Alternatively, an one-liner using D3 v5.8 shorthand:

```
const scale = d3.scaleLinear([0,10,50,500], [0, 33.3, 66.6, 100]);
```

Let's see it in action:

```js
const svg = d3.select("svg");
const scale = d3.scaleLinear()
  .domain([0, 10, 50, 500])
  .range([0, 33.3, 66.6, 100]);
const circles = svg.selectAll(null)
  .data(d3.range(0, 500, 2))
  .enter()
  .append("circle")
  .attr("r", 2)
  .attr("cx", (_, i) => 5 + i * 2 + 1)
  .attr("cy", d => 105 - scale(d));
```

```css
svg {
  background-color: wheat;
}

circle {
  fill: none;
  stroke: gray;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/d3/5.7.0/d3.min.js"></script>
<svg width="510" height="110"></svg>
```

Of course, a better practice would be creating the range dynamically, based on the number of elements in the domain:

```js
const scale = d3.scaleLinear()
  .domain([0, 10, 50, 500]);

scale.range(d3.range(0, 100 + 100 / (scale.domain().length - 1), 100 / (scale.domain().length - 1)))

console.log(scale.range())
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/d3/5.7.0/d3.min.js"></script>
```